# list View divider even no data is to show in the list View

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to show listView divider all over in the listView even no data to show in the listView

I am working on an Application where I have to fetch data from data base and show in the listView

If there are only two records in the data base the divider should be shown after these two records in the listView or if there is no record in the database then there will be no data to show in the listView but I want to show the divider even when there is no data to show

I am using the following code but could not solve my problem.

```
<com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView 
android:id="@+id/    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/linehoro"
android:background="#f3e9ca"
android:divider="#92d4c6"
android:dividerHeight="1sp"
android:footerDividersEnabled="true"></ListView>
```

I could find no similar questions on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the rest of adapter with dummy data, depending on the screen size of course.

```
Data data = new Data("","",""); //something like that.
```

Comment: can you please elaborate it means with an example , i am using baseAdabpter

Comment: because i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Create a textview with your divider style and add this textview as emptyview.

```
lstView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Comment: basically i am using a custom listView (com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView  a third aparty listView)  for the Swipe to delete the listView item, i tried to your answer but did not work for me, any other suggestions